# Reduce spacing in gravity form fields

Tags: wordpress, css, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm having issues styling the form created with gravity forms plugin. The space between the fields top and bottom are too much. I need help please

Its on the [footer of my website](http://www.martcircle.com)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this css

```
body .gform_wrapper ul li.gfield {
 margin-top: 0 !important;
}

.block-content ul li {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but spaces still there.

Answer (score 0):

Add this css

```
<style>
    body .gform_wrapper ul li.gfield {
        margin-top: 0px !important;
        padding-top: 0;
    }
    .block-content ul li {
          margin-bottom: 0 !important;
          margin-top: 0 !important;
        }
    .gform_body ul li .ginput_container select,.gform_body ul li .ginput_container input{
            margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .gform_wrapper .top_label .gfield_label {
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Awesome! it worked. Many Thanks

Do you have an idea how I can link the dropdown fields to display wordpress categories and the other dropdown to display the list of locations.

Comment: @BeckyAbe, you can link drop down to category

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm asking if any1 knows how to achieve. Thanks

Comment: @BeckyAbe, This question is answered. so you should post new.

Answer (score 0):

```
.gform_body ul li, .gform_body input, .gform_body div{ 
    margin: 0;
}
```

You can also add .gform_body textarea etc...

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
.gform-theme--api, .gform-theme--foundation {
--gform-theme-form-row-gap: 10px; }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).